# how to store CryptoJS encrypted password in database

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash, firebase, cryptojs

i am quite new to CRYPTO JS encrypted stuff and i am trying to store encryted hash in database(I am trying to store in firebase database).

```
    var hash = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('my message', 'secret key 123');
```

I am trying to store hash variable in database.
But when i am trying to store, it shows me error that it is function, not possible to store.

PS- i am trying to store encryted hash in databse and want to call encrpted hash  on another page of my application from database and decrypt there.

Is that possible? if yes, then please tell me how.
Thanks

Comment: Hi m03a3a17, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are getting an error when you run your code, then you need to show that error in your question; otherwise it is very difficult for anybody to know exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: okay man... thanks.. i will try it next time.... btw do you think i asked good question

Comment: AES is an encryption algorithm (reversible) and not a hash function (non-reversible). Please don't confuse them. Passwords must be hashed, but a single hash isn't enough, because attackers have fast password hashing machines. You need to hash it repeatedly. Functions for this is something like PBKDF2 which is supported by CryptoJS. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database.

Comment: See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: thanks very much.. you almost clear me the concept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `hash` is an object, you need to call `hash.toString()` to convert it into a string.

From the CryptoJS github page:

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA3("Message");

//The hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a WordArray object.
//When you use a WordArray object in a string context,
//it's automatically converted to a hex string. 
alert(hash.toString()); //Same as hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

```js
// Import and use instance for TypeScript.
import * as crypto from "crypto-js";
console.log(crypto.SHA256("password").toString());
```

Comment: Thanks.. this answer help me,, can you tell me how to decpryt this also?

Comment: `var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(hash, 'secret key 123');` Other examples: http://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/crypto-js-tutorial-cryptography-for-dummies/ - please post follow-up questions as new questions on StackOverflow and don't add new questions in comments ;) Please also mark the answer as "accepted" if it answers your original question.